# Generate Arabic content with PDFKit & nodeJS

Tags: node.js, pdfkit

i'm using pdfkit with nodejs to generate dynamically PDF files. the generation works fine but i have a problem displaying arabic characters even if i setup a font that support arabic.

The letters are rendered correctly, but the words are displayed character by character :(

here's my code

```
doc = new PDFDocument;
doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('output.pdf'));
var str = "فصل الربيع الزهور \n#nature #payesage #fleurs #plantes #vert #espace #temara #rabat #maroc #WeekEnd #balade #instamoment #instalife #instamaroc #photographie #macro #peace";
doc.font('resources/HelveticaNeueLTArabic-Roman.ttf').text(str);
```

Any thoughts or suggestions will be great.

Comment: Just found out they are switching to **fontkit** for their font engine. Which will bring better support for Arabic languages.

Answer (score 1):

Use Amiri font , it supports arabic font

```
const customFontRegular = fs.readFileSync(`./amiri/Amiri-Regular.ttf`);
const customFontBold = fs.readFileSync(`./amiri/Amiri-Bold.ttf`);

pdfDoc.registerFont(`Amiri-Regular`, customFontRegular);
pdfDoc.registerFont(`Amiri-Bold`, customFontBold);
```

And it can be used as

```
pdfDoc.font('Amiri-Regular').text("Hello world");
```

Comment: Can you explain where the variable `fontBold` in the second code block comes from?

Comment: You can specify the font name to fontBold variable , for example const fontBold="Amiri-Bold";